# How to create method chaining like laravel in native php?

Tags: php, laravel

In laravel i often see method chaining like:

Class::method1()->method2->method3->method4()->etc();

Or example in laravel

Route::get()->name()->middleware();

And my question is How can i create a simple sintax like that on native php?

Comment: I think that you could do some research about, and in that achieve if some issue come here for assistance

Answer (score 1):

The basics behind this is creating classes with functions that return `$this`. Example:

```
class Table {
    private $color;
    private $legs;

    public function color($color){
        $this->color = $color;
        return $this;
    }
    public function legs($legs){
        $this->legs = $legs;
        return $this;
    }
}
```

This allows for the following code:

```
$table = new Table(); 
$table->color('black')->legs(4);
```

Comment: Thanks you, but in my example Route isn't a variable,its a class without instantiate

Comment: Actually, the Route class you're accessing is a so-called Facade. Check out https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/facades

Comment: Thanks you, so would you please to create a simple example about that,like your first answer